# Preposition on Mode of Transport

Tags: prepositions

I am studying preposition related to mode of transportation (English is not my first language). Despite knowing the rule for by, on, in prepositions, I still find them confusing. Can you tell how below sentences differ?

I am in a bus.
I am on a bus.

I travelled by bus.
I travelled on a bus.
I travelled in a bus.

Thank you.

Comment: I might say 'I travelled by bus' if I had chosen that particular mode of transport for a longer journey.. I would be more likely to say 'I went there on the bus' if I was referring to a familiar, local bus service.